# Determine whether the given set is closed under the usual addition and scalar multiplication, and is a (real) vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The set of all 2 x 2 matrices of the form

\begin{bmatrix}
    x & 1 \\
    1 & x
\end{bmatrix}

Where each $x$ may be any scalar

---

I don't get why this doesn't close under addition textbook says thats the reason this isn't a vector space.

Comment: Try adding two of them. Any two of them, it doesn't matter which.

Comment: Incidentally, the body of your post should be self-contained -- it's okay to duplicate information in the title, but nothing important should be *only* in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x & 1\\1&x\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}y & 1\\1&y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x+y & \color{red}{2}\\\color{red}{2}&x+y\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: What does it mean to be closed under addition then? I don't get how this proves it

Comment: @jimmyjimmy Let the set be $S$ whose elements are the matrices of the given form. The set is closed under addition if the sum of any two elements in $S$ results in another element in $S$. Does $\begin{bmatrix}x+y & \color{red}{2}\\\color{red}{2}&x+y\end{bmatrix}$ belong to $S$?

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
    x & 1 \\
    1 & x
\end{bmatrix} thats S? It has to stay that form, correct? Since adding them the new matrix arent in that form so that means it not closed under addition? Thats what I'm getting at

Comment: @jimmyjimmy Yes, you got it right.